# MarkLogic LDAP authentication

Tags: authentication, ldap, marklogic, marklogic-9

I'm running ML9 on a MacOS. I am trying to setup External Authentication (and Authorization eventually) on Query Console (on App-Server port 8000).

I have:
1. Created OpenLDAP server with some users
2. Created LDAP config with below details:

```
Name: ExtLDAP
authentication: ldap
authorization: internal
ldap server uri: ldap://localhost:389
ldap base: dc=babji,dc=com
ldap attribute: cn
ldap default user: cn=Manager,dc=babji,dc=com
ldap password: [password of the above default user in OpenLDAP database]
ldap bind method: simple
ldap memberof attribute: ou
ldap memer attribute: ou
ssl require client certificate: false
```

3. Updated Query Console App-Services [port 8000] with below details:

   authentication: basic
       internal security: false
       external securities: ExtLDAP
       default user: nobody
4. Created an internal user with below details:

name: ldapuser
external name: cn=Newer Surname,ou=BizUser,dc=babji,dc=com

5. Tested below: **Successful**

   xdmp:ldap-search(
     "sn=Surname",
      options xmlns="xdmp:ldap">
     username>cn=Manager,dc=babji,dc=com
     password>xxxx
     server-uri>ldap://localhost:389
     search-base>ou=BiZUser,dc=babji,dc=com
     bind-method>simple
    /options>)
   (Forgive the format above. I was unable to change this to a code format.)

ldapsearch works too:

```
ldapsearch -D "cn=manager,dc=babji,dc=com" -b dc=babji,dc=com -W objectclass=*
```

Issue:

When I try to login to query console using the browser with one of the cn entries (users) in the LDAP database, I am unable to login.
Also, below command **does not work**.

```
xdmp:http-get("http://localhost:8000",
     <options xmlns="xdmp:http">
       <authentication>
         <username>Newer Surname</username>
         <password>xxxx</password>
       </authentication>
     </options>)
```

I am unsure what configurations should I put in the config page. Can you please help or re-direct me to a right location?

regards,
Bharadwaj

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 parts involved:

1. Auth set to basic or application
2. Internal security to false
3. An external security object created *and* used (as a bridge to your external security service)

Once you created the external security object, did you remember to go back to your app server config and actually configure it to use the security object?

Also, you mention nothing about the log files. How about posting the error (if any) from there.

**My suggested steps for you to go back through and verify:**

Please look at this chapter:
https://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/guide/security/external-auth#id_81861

Then proceed to the external security object configuration section:
https://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/guide/security/external-auth#id_35317

And finally, the actual configuration of the app server to use the object(it sounds like you have done 1/2 of this already):
https://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/guide/security/external-auth#id_63262

Comment: David, Thanks for the reply.
1) I am running on ML "9". It has a new sections in LDAP config - member attribute and memberOf attribute. ML 8 (as per the training course) required memberOf attribute. It shows optional in the ldap config page. Is it correct?
2) If you look at my question, you would find the configuration I have used based on the documentation you have provided already. Request you to re-read my question with configuration settings. I will be honest and I did not understand from the required config changes to be made from the documentation
3)I am still learning openLDAP. HELP!

Comment: and - I have set the log level to finest and I still do not see 8000_AccessLog.txt not showing the finest. It only shows the session information in 1 line :(

Comment: I posted all of the steps because you never specifically state that you used the configuration object in the app server (just that you created one - which is an idependent step). Second - If I were looking for errors - I would be looking in the error logs and not the access logs.

Comment: Hi, it still does not help somehow and I stand clueless. May be I am making some mistake in setting up ldap users. Could anyone share *both* of ML9 settings and OpenLdap users that I can refer to?